# Command pattern + pagination

Tags: php, rest, symfony, cqrs, command-pattern

I have some command which is used to get some collection of objects.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Domain\Query;

class GetCardsByNetworkId
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $network_id;

    public function __construct(int $network_id)
    {
        $this->network_id = $network_id;
    }

    public function network_id(): int
    {
        return $this->network_id;
    }
}
```

but I need pagination on results.

For now I placed pagination as parameter to handle method as below but I feel that handle should only have one parameter - Command.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Domain\Query;

use App\Projection\Card\CardFinder;

class GetCardsByNetworkIdHandler
{
    /**
     * @var CardFinder
     */
    private $cardFinder;

    public function __construct(CardFinder $cardFinder)
    {
        $this->cardFinder = $cardFinder;
    }

    public function handle(GetCardsByNetworkId $query, int $itemsPerPage, int $page)
    {
        $card = $this->cardFinder->findAllForNetworkId($query->network_id(), $itemsPerPage, $page);

        return $card;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

How to do that correct? Should I place pagination params to my command?

Comment: what framework do you use?

Comment: Symfony but I think this is not important here? You want say that this should be done by my framework?

Comment: It seems like a framework related issue. Who and how does the `handle` method being called?

Comment: This is called from rest api, and I give rest api client possibility to change itemsPerPage so this should be passed to command or handler somehow. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't use Symfony but I will try to help. How does the REST url looks like?

Comment: http://myurl/api/cards?_page=1&_itemsPerPage=1

Comment: and with applied filters? i.e. network_id

Comment: this parameter is get from session so it is not available in api parameters. So you have experience with that and you claim that should be done by framework - this pagination, not by command or handler?

Comment: I don't have any experience with Symfony. I suspect that the solution has something to do with the *magic* behind the Symfony. I've added the `Symfony` tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks Constantin

Answer (score 2):

You should ask for itemsPerPage and page arguments in your GetCardsByNetworkId construct.

It will prevent your Command to handle pagination validation (itemPerPage > 0, page >= 1, ...) and validate your inputs before you even pass the GetCardsByNetworkId to your commandBus.

You'll have something like :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Domain\Query;

class GetCardsByNetworkId
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $network_id;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $itemsPerPage;
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $page;


    public function __construct(
        int $network_id,
        int $itemsPerPage,
        int $page
    ) {
        $this->network_id = $network_id;
        IsGreaterThan::validate(0, $itemsPerPage);
        IsGreaterThan::validate(0, $page);
        $this->itemsPerPage = $itemsPerPage;
        $this->page = $page;
    }

    public function network_id(): int
    {
        return $this->network_id;
    }

    public function getItemsPerPage(): int
    {
        return $this->itemPerPage;
    }

    public function getPage(): int
    {
        return $this->page;
    }
}
```

Where IsGreaterThan class is your assert implementation which should throw an exception (i.e. : \InvalidArgument) if not satisfied.

Comment: Could you provide some article or something to confirm that this attitude is the best :)?

Comment: All the dispatcher should care about is the command that it should dispatch, so this is in fact the correct way to do it. A command should accept everything that it needs to do the task - including which page of results you want to fetch.

Comment: @Arkowsky, sure :) I recommend this Matthias Noback Blog post that give a lot of answers about Command bus (see the "How to return a value from the command bus" part). https://matthiasnoback.nl/2015/01/some-questions-about-the-command-bus/